# Nativescript - Running code when app is close

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I would know if, using Nativescript, is it possible to create an application that on specific event (onclick) "register" a javascript function that will run always and indipendently from the app (this means either if the app is open or close) until another event "unregister" the function.

If it is possible can you direct me to the right construct to manage this situation? I heard about workers but i cant understand is can use it to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use background-tasks which will run when the app is sent to the background.. for a long term execution you would need the user permission.
nativescript docs: https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/how-to/BackgroundExecution

**edit:** you can wake a closed app into the background in respond to events.. (notification..etc) so a running app is either an active foreground app(visible on the screen) or a background app(running but not active, can be seen from the app switcher)..

Comment: what means "background"? is it when the app is completely close?